# Is there a regular expression to match every possible lowercase letter?

Tags: regex, unicode

This seems like a trivial question, but it's really not. I'm trying to craft a regular expression that can match everything that is a lowercase letter, or looks like one. My first naive attempt was simply to use this:

```
/[a-z]+/
```

However, that doesn't match `ESPAñOL` because `ñ` falls outside the range. So then I tried building a needlessly long regular expression with a whole lot of Unicode characters, before realizing there must be a better way. This lead me down a rabbit hole where I eventually discovered [Unicode code points](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) and then crafted this simple regex:

```
/\p{Ll}+/
```

However, I subsequently learned that not even this one succeeds if you introduce certain subscript or superscript characters which are apparently not officially classified as lowercase, even though they sure look a lot like lowercase. Here's an example of a string which the above regex does *not* match:

> THIS LOOKS A LOT LIKE ₗₒₑᵣₐₛₑ

So then I thought that maybe I could just explicitly include superscript and subscript characters in my regex, like this:

```
/\p{Ll}+|\p{In_Superscripts_and_Subscripts}+/
```

However that is unfortunately too aggressive, as it will match strings like `A²` which clearly don't contain anything that looks lowercase. I do see that there is a `\p{Numeric_Type=Digit}` character class, but I'm not sure how to craft a regex to look for one type (In_Superscripts_and_Subscripts) that simultaneously excludes another type (Numeric_Type=Digit). Is there some way to select only the superscripts and subscripts that look like they're lowercase?

Answer (score 1):

You're somewhat close, but you're checking the wrong thing. `\p{Ll}` tests whether a code point is in the General Category "Lowercase Letter." `ₗ` is in the category "Modifier Letter." What you wanted to check is the `lowercase` property: `/\p{lowercase}/`.

That said,  is in the Lowercase Letter General Category. If `THIS LOOKS A LOT LIKE ₗₒₑᵣₐₛₑ` does not match `/\p{Ll}/`, that suggests a bug in your regex engine.

Swift, as an example, does correctly match these cases:

```swift
let message = "THIS LOOKS A LOT LIKE ₗₒₑᵣₐₛₑ"
message.firstMatch(of: /\p{lowercase}/)!.output  // "ₗ"
message.firstMatch(of: /\p{Ll}/)!.output  // ""
```